# Getting other nodes as children for the xml node while parsing from xml document object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

We have Document object creation from my xml file is as below.

```
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setValidating(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse("D:/ABC.xml");
            document.normalize();
```

Getting child nodes from created document logic is as below.

```
public void getDataFromXML()
{
            Node rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
            int childsCount = rootElement.getChildNodes().getLength();
            for(index = 0; index < childsCount; index ++ )
            {
                Node item = rootElement.getChildNodes().item(index);

                printXMLNode(item);
             }
   }



    public synchronized void printXMLNode(Node xmlNode)
    {
            int nodesLength = xmlNode.getChildNodes().getLength();
            System.out.println("XML-DEBUG : "+xmlNode);
            for(int attribCount = 0; attribCount < nodesLength; ++ attribCount)
            {
                    Node attribute = xmlNode.getChildNodes().item(attribCount);
                    System.out.println("\t\t "+attribCount+" "+attribute);
            }
    }
```

Two threads are trying to call the same method from different places:
     Ex for one thread call is below:

```
Thread test = new Thread(){
  public void run()
  {
  while(true)
   {
    getDataFromXML();                          
      }    
   }         
    };                 
    test.start();
```

Input XML is :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE Script SYSTEM "Script.dtd">
<Script>
<setValue>
<Label>User Name</Label>
<Value>sysadmin</Value>
</setValue>
<setValue>
<Label>Password</Label>
<Value>XXX</Value>
</setValue>
<click>
<Label>Login</Label>
</click>
<click>
<Label>Purchasing Super User</Label>
</click>
<click>
<Label>Requisitions[1]</Label>
</click>
<click>
<Label>Requisitions[2]</Label>
</click>
<SetText>
<Value>Vision Operations</Value>
</SetText>
<KeyPress>
<Label>Operating Unit0</Label>
</KeyPress>
<SetText>
<Value>Purchase Requisition</Value>
</SetText>
<KeyPress>
<Label>Type0</Label>
</KeyPress>
<SetText>
<Label>Description</Label>
<Value/>
<Disable>True</Disable>
<Comment/>
</SetText>
<KeyPress>
<Label>Description0</Label>
</KeyPress>
</Script>
```

The out put of the method(printXMLNode) is getting differently at different times for some node(not for same node everytime).
Sometimes, expected outcome comes, but sometimes not.

For ex, for SetText node,the Expected output is :

```
XML-DEBUG : [SetText: null]
0 [#text: 
1 [Value: null]
2 [#text:
```

Strage output is :

```
XML-DEBUG : [SetText: null]
     0 [setValue: null]
     1 [setValue: null]
     2 [click: null]
     3 [click: null]
     4 [click: null]
     5 [click: null]
     6 [SetText: null]
     7 [KeyPress: null]
     8 [SetText: null]
     9 [KeyPress: null]
     10 [SetText: null]
     11 [KeyPress: null]
```

Unable to understand why the results are varying.Few threads are trying to get data from this method, that's why we kept this method as synchonized, even though problem persists.
Could any one please help out on this?

Comment: The error is probably the line `Node attribute = item.getChildNodes().item(attribCount);` it should be `Node attribute = xmlNode.getChildNodes().item(attribCount);`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change there while posting. :)

Comment: Now I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: You mention that the date is processed with multiply threads, but the code doesn't contains that. Please complete your code so that its possible to reproduce your error.

Comment: Provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have provided sample code of thread from which the method is calling and also methods.Like that thread, we have one more thread which runs always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to realise, the DOM is not thread-safe. You have synchronized one method that accesses the DOM, but your method getDataFromXML also uses DOM methods and is not synchronized.

If you need multithreading, there are better APIs than DOM. Both JDOM2 and XOM are thread-safe (I believe) if all threads are only reading.

Even better, do the whole thing in XQuery or XSLT.

Comment: Yes, there may be better ways to do it.But as of now, I cant change the entire logic.It is enough having only synchronized method for reading part, why becoz that method only does whole thing.